# Permutation of pencils in box

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**You have 3 red, 4 blue and 5 green pencils. How many ways are there, to arrange all these pencils in box, with condition, that none of blue pencils are adjacent to each other?**

Okay:

1. Let's arrange all red and green pencils: $$\frac{8!}{3!5!}$$
2. Now we have 9 empty places, and we can place blue pencil in any of it. This gives us: $C_9^4$
3. So we have: $$\frac{8!9!}{3!5!4!5!} = 7056$$

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean none of the blue pencils are next to each other, and no layering is allowed in the box but just a linear arrangement in one row, you are correct.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, thank you